# PHP7.0 File Uploads With No Errors but 0 bytes

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a small php snippet that performs an file upload; however, the file is loaded with 0 bytes:

```
if( 0 < $FILES["file"]["error"]){
    echo "Error With The Uploaded File";
} else {
    $filename = "/Server/Client/Uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);     
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$filename)){
        chmod($filename, 0775);
    } else {
        echo "Error Uploading File..."
    }
}
```

A dump on the file indicates size and no error:

```
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "12-24-2015.pdf"
    ["type"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php1E6GbF"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(2176969)
  }
}
```

This file is actually saved at the specified location but the size is zero.  The destination server is Ubuntu Linux 15.10.  I don't see a permissions issue as the file is actually being written.  Anything else I should look at?  Thanks.

Comment: did you checked post max size, upload  file size in php.ini file, and restart your server...

Comment: post max size and upload max size are properly set in the php.ini file.

Comment: Does `/tmp/php1E6GbF` have the correct size or it's empty as well? Have you enabled full error reporting?

Comment: Alvaro didn't think to turn on full error reporting...looks to be a permission issue afterall.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$filename = "/Server/Client/Uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);` – careful, that might make your script vulnerable to path traversal attacks.

Comment: CBroe - the path I actually use isn't literal.  I changed the names to protect the innocent.  Thanks though.